# Vue3 - router push to another page only renders top part of the page - not scrollable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am experiencing an issue that I actually already have had for quite some time.
My setup is Vue3 and Vuetify 3.

Whenever I change the page after some kind of calculation:

```
    router.push({ name: 'AnotherPage', params: { id: index, variable: x} });
```

The page is redirected to 'AnotherPage' but the page is not scrollable, so only the part of the page that fits on the page is rendered.

After doing an F5 refresh, the complete page is rendered and scrollable.

I only noticed this behavior when I was looking into redirecting to a certain section on a page, using anchors, and found that it was not working.

```
scrollToElement() {
  if (this.$route.hash) {
    const targetId = ref(this.$route.hash.replace('#', ''));
    const eal = document.getElementById(targetId.value);
    if (eal != null) {
      eal.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
},
```

This works when I load the page from scratch, but it doesn't when I use the aforementioned router.push method. There is no error though, so the component is able to find the element linked to the requested anchor tag.

Another thing is that when I perform a hardcoded router.push from a button click, it works!

Comment: The bug you describe cannot be reproduced using the details you provided so far. I suggest creating a *runnable* [mcve] using codesandbox.io or similar. Note codesandbox allows you to [import local projects](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) fairly easy. I would also suggest you add details on how to reproduce the bug, once you create the sandbox (e.g: navigate from X to Y).

Comment: you shouldn't have to emulate a `click` in order to render properly. You claim you're running out of options in the question. Create a [mcve] and I'll try to provide you with a proper fix. Without a runnable example I have no way of knowing what's wrong with what you have now, nor would I be able to test any potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vuejs there is a parent-child dependency between elements. It is not clear from the question if views are used, but I assume so, because that's a best practice.

- `router.push` is for [history manipulation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html): so if you do that from the **parent** main-view it will work, and inform automatically a child-view to re-render (because of the change itself)
- but if you do the calculation deeper in the page, in a **child**, and want to update the entire page, you have to use the `emit` [component event](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) (the child informs the parents about the change of values and for a re-render)

See this example for a demo: https://learnvue.co/tutorials/vue-emit-guide

To put it together: having a `update` function in the mainView, which wants to be called from a `RouterLink` in a childView. This is started by `updateParent` - so there a emit event `prev-next-click` is defined.

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<script>
export default {
  emits: ['prev-next-click'],
  methods: {
    updateParent: function(c, d) {
      // on button click update from fixture
      // emit a call from subView (child) to run the update in main App (parent) 
      this.$emit("prev-next-click", c, d);
    },
    to: function (c=this.category, d=this.today) {
      return { name: 'quote', params: { category: c, day: d }}
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.updateParent(this.$route.params.category, this.$route.params.day);
  }
};
</script>

<template>
    <RouterLink class="button prev" :to="to(category,prev)" @click="updateParent(category,prev)">click</RouterLink>
</template>
```

And the mainView glue it together with `RouterView` (not the name of the view!)

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    update: function (c, d) {
      console.log("update c", c, "d", d);
    },
  },
}
</script>

<template>
    <RouterView @prev-next-click="update"/>
</template>
```

**Update to the comment:**

A problem I had to solve with the code above, was that the childView wasn't rendered properly when initialized. That's why childView always call `updateParent` once directly during creation by the `created` hook.

See [vuejs lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html) for all other hooks - maybe the `updated` fits in your case.

Comment: This looks quite plausible! I am not quite familiar with your way of coding, but I did implement the emit in the views. I had to repeat the process around 6 times to get to the parent component. Unfortunately, when I did the router.push in there, it didn't work either. Is this more or less the same as your code? I do get the emit response after emitting in through 6 layers, and the requested page is displayed, although only the upper part is visualized (the same problem as before).

Comment: @helloworld Maybe I've run into similar problem, only when pressing F5 the page was correct, as I remember. See my updated answer about the "vuejs lifecycle" - maybe you also need `created` or maybe the `updated` hook.

Comment: hi admirableadmin, i made some progress. A button with a router push action method linked to it works from a parent component view. The same button does not work from a child component. So far so good. Next, I changed it so that the child component emits to the parent component, is reaching the same method on the parent page. The router push is executed but it fails! So only showing part of the view. So your tips are in the right direction. If I can't figure it out in the coming weekend, I'll award you with the award.

Comment: I didn't get it to work with the router push using emits to the main component. I fixed it using another method. Basically a simple :href for buttons, and if I want to use that programmatically, emulate a click. Here is some examples:             <v-btn :href="helpLink">More info</v-btn>


     <v-btn ref="buttonRef" icon :href="getLink">
             <v-icon>mdi-nature-people</v-icon>
          </v-btn>

    this.$refs.buttonRef.$el.click();

Comment: still, i think admireablieadmin reply is still valid, as he did come up with a good explanation.

Comment: I'm happy my answer helped you. Also `RouterLink` seperate the target (:to) from a functional event (click). It's a declarative way instead the programmatic router.push - The main thing is that it works properly for you :-)